What is the difference between [cognitive-psychology] and [cognition]?
Our most popular tag (24 questions) is cognitive-psychology which seems to be applied pretty widely. We also, have a relatively popular (7 questions) cognition tag. However, I don't understand the difference between the two tags. In particular, I feel like many of the questions tagged with one of the tags, could have been tagged with the other.
When would I use cognitive-psychology and when would I use cognition?

Cog Psych is a specific branch of psychology that's reasonably well defined though it applies to many questions here. Cognition is vague to the point that most questions on the site could be tagged with it. IMO, it's like having a [Programming] tag on Stack Overflow. I think we should ax it for more specific terms like attention, memory ect.

@BenBrocka do we want to ax it or merge it with CogPsych?

I'm not 100% sure how we want to apple Cog Psych, IMO all of those questions would be fine if we just axed cognition.

@BenBrocka Okay, I will ax and then just include the questions in an answer to this question, in case someone wants to quickly un-ax later

I went through and removed the cognition tag (and sometimes added the CogPsych tag) from the following questions:
By learning to read and write upside down, what did I do to myself?
Does language and/or culture affect an individual's cognitive capacity?
Does learning one discipline improve performance in another discipline?
Cognitive explanation of why beta blockers are effective for anxiety
Research suggesting conscious control over brain region activation?
Can intense multitasking improve fluid intelligence/working memory?
Any work being done on Perception, Action, and/or Cognition in Video games?
Is it possible for humans to conceive of being dead?
I included the links just in case there is a problem with the removal down the line.

I was hoping that retagging would bump the questions, but it did... now the whole front page is littered with my name. Sorry!

No problem Artem, it's better to clean up now than later! Thanks for taking care of this.
